# Meaning of * * in aiml file

Tags: artificial-intelligence, aiml

I was given the following code in AIML:

```
<category>
 <pattern>TOP * *</pattern>
 <template><star index="1"/></template>
</category>
```

Which is supposed to give back the first element of a list of words.
I know * is supposed to capture one or more words. What is the meaning of * *?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned * captures one or more words. First star would capture one word, rest would be captured by second one. Your template uses only first star thus first element of the list.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a while since you asked this. I had a similar problem and found the XSPLITTER word (as any other, but works as a flag), what you can do (what I'm working in right now) is to filter the inputs and add the XSPLITTER word matching a regex in your interpreter. Or, even easier, in your very case, you can just edit the AIML file and replace your pattern with this:

```
<category>
    <pattern>TOP * IN *</pattern>
    <template><star index="1"/></template>
</category>
```

Not really sure if it makes sense as I don't know what you want to top and where, but as a starting point it can work.

Comment: I cannot really pay attention to your answer to validate it as the best one. Should we leave this to the community votes? Anyway thanks for your answer (maybe one day I come back to aiml, you never know)